# calculating limit by second moment argument

Tags: probability, expected-value, moment-generating-functions, derivation-of-formulae

Let $0<p<1$ be fixed.

Let $X_n$, $n=1,2,...$, be a sequence of random variables with non-negative integer values.

Suppose their expectations satisfy $E(X_n)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2} p^{n-2}$.

***Question :*** How can we use a standard second moment argument to prove  $\lim_{n\to\infty} \text{Prob}\{X_n=0\}=0$?

Reference:

*Linial, Nathan; Meshulam, Roy*, [**Homological connectivity of random 2-complexes**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00493-006-0027-9), Combinatorica 26, No. 4, 475-487 (2006). [ZBL1121.55013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1121.55013).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It seems the context is that the author claimed the limit is zero and claimed that this is easy by a standard second moment argument. But as is so often the case when authors do that, the reader finds it is not that easy for them